# Check if two values exist on a database and return which one or both with one consultation

Tags: php, pdo

I'm trying to check if an username or email exists in a database and return data to the user saying if the email or username or both are already in use, there is any way to do this without making two consultations to the database? 
for now I have this↓ but I'm not sure it's right.

```
 <?php
    if (isset($_POST['sub'])){
     require_once 'conexio.php';
     $pdo = new Conexio(); 
     $pdo->exec("set names utf8");

     $dbTabla="usuaris";
     $contra = $_POST["contra"];

     $consulta=$pdo->prepare("SELECT username,email FROM $dbTabla WHERE username=? OR email=?");
     $consulta->execute(array($_POST['username'],$_POST['email']));
     $result = $consulta->fetchObject();
     if($consulta->rowCount()>0){


     if("what to put in here?"){

      echo "That username it's already in use";

     }

     if("what to put in here?"){

      echo "That e-mail it's already in use";

     }
                             }



   }

   ?>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "problem" with your current query (and with the solution suggested by Chinnu) is that it may return up to two rows (one matching the username and one matching the email) you may have to iterate through, which may be a bit annoying.

You could get a single row result using the `BIT_OR` aggregate function:

```
$consulta=$pdo->prepare("SELECT BIT_OR(username = ?) AS username_exists, " .
                        "BIT_OR(email = ?) AS email_exists " . 
                        "FROM $dbTabla " .
                        "WHERE username=? OR email=?");
$consulta->execute(array($_POST['username'], $_POST['email'],$_POST['username'], $_POST['email']));
```

Now, you have a single row with true/false expressions that can easily be evaluated:

```
if($result->username_exists) {
    echo "That username is already in use";
}

if($result->email_exists) {
    echo "That e-mail is already in use";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this,

```
    $result = $consulta->fetchObject();

    if($result->username==$_POST['username']){
            echo "That username it's already in use";
    }

    if($result->email==$_POST['email']){
        echo "That e-mail it's already in use";
    }
```